# Dynamic update with live data loading functionality in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, r-dygraphs

I'm new to R and i dont have backgroup on js. I'm trying to develop shiny app.
I've been looking for the dynamic update with live data loading functionality on dygraph R, which is like this: https://kaliatech.github.io/dygraphs-dynamiczooming-example/example6.html

I looked into the R dygraph docs for couple of times, i did not find the solution for my case.

Any idea how can i achieve this in shiny R?

Rgds

Comment: May be you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before ..

Comment: Refer this [reactiveTimer](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/reactiveTimer.html)

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington, thanks for your suggestions, i'll make it better in my second question.

Comment: @amrrs , Thanks for the reply, i may not be clear enough, i've achieved the accumulate dynamic data trend plotting in dygraph, but that is not what i want. 

I want the data shown in a certain time window(saying 24hrs) ,and shift to left for those data out of date.

Which is exactly similar to below example:
[link](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=dynamic-data2)

Not sure how to do this with dygraph.